# Mouse pointer - reason for it changing direction in visual studio

Tags: cursor

We all know the generic arrow mouse pointer points to the left, however in visual studio if you hover over the line number column in your editor it switches and points to the right. Does anybody know the reasoning behind this?

I can't grab a screenshot unfortunately as it won't capture the cursor!

Comment: possibly because if it were pointing to the left, it would be covering up the text that you are trying to read when reading left to right.